# Displaying UTF-8 Emoji in Java

Tags: java, utf-8, byte, emoji, utf-16

Say I have the  (devil) emoji.

In 4-byte UTF-8, it's represented like so: `\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0088`

However, in Java, it will only print correctly like so: `\ud83d\ude08`

How would I convert from the first to the second?

**UPDATE 2**

MNEMO's answer is much simpler, and answers my question, so it's probably better to go with his solution.

**UPDATE**

Thanks Basil Bourque for the write-up.  It was very interesting.

I found a good reference here: https://github.com/pRizz/Unicode-Converter/blob/master/conversionfunctions.js (particularly the convertUTF82Char() function).

For anyone wandering by here in the future, here's what that looks like in Java:

```
public static String fromCharCode(int n) {
    char c = (char)n;
    return Character.toString(c);
}

public static String decToChar(int n) {
    // converts a single string representing a decimal number to a character
    // note that no checking is performed to ensure that this is just a hex number, eg. no spaces etc
    // dec: string, the dec codepoint to be converted
    String result = "";
    if (n <= 0xFFFF) {
        result += fromCharCode(n);
    } else if (n <= 0x10FFFF) {
        n -= 0x10000;
        result += fromCharCode(0xD800 | (n >> 10)) + fromCharCode(0xDC00 | (n & 0x3FF));
    } else {
        result += "dec2char error: Code point out of range: " + decToHex(n);
    }

    return result;
}

public static String decToHex(int n) {
    return Integer.toHexString(n).toUpperCase();
}

public static String convertUTF8_toChar(String str) {
    // converts to characters a sequence of space-separated hex numbers representing bytes in utf8
    // str: string, the sequence to be converted
    var outputString = "";
    var counter = 0;
    var n = 0;

    // remove leading and trailing spaces
    str = str.replaceAll("/^\\s+/", "");
    str = str.replaceAll("/\\s+$/", "");
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    str = str.replaceAll("/\\s+/g", " ");

    var listArray = str.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
        int b = parseInt(listArray[i], 16); // alert('b:'+dec2hex(b));
        switch (counter) {
            case 0:
                if (0 <= b && b <= 0x7F) { // 0xxxxxxx
                    outputString += decToChar(b);
                } else if (0xC0 <= b && b <= 0xDF) { // 110xxxxx
                    counter = 1;
                    n = b & 0x1F;
                } else if (0xE0 <= b && b <= 0xEF) { // 1110xxxx
                    counter = 2;
                    n = b & 0xF;
                } else if (0xF0 <= b && b <= 0xF7) { // 11110xxx
                    counter = 3;
                    n = b & 0x7;
                } else {
                    outputString += "convertUTF82Char: error1 " + decToHex(b) + "! ";
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (b < 0x80 || b > 0xBF) {
                    outputString += "convertUTF82Char: error2 " + decToHex(b) + "! ";
                }
                counter--;
                outputString += decToChar((n << 6) | (b - 0x80));
                n = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
                if (b < 0x80 || b > 0xBF) {
                    outputString += "convertUTF82Char: error3 " + decToHex(b) + "! ";
                }
                n = (n << 6) | (b - 0x80);
                counter--;
                break;
        }
    }

    return outputString.replaceAll("/ $/", "");
}
```

Pretty much a 1-for-1 copy, but it accomplishes my goal.

Comment: It is recommended to learn more about character encoding and Unicode system if you want to solve the problem. 4-byte UTF-8 is a sequence of bytes, but not an Unicode codepoint itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, this is quite unnecessary to add, but after you understand all character encoding system and Unicode concept, following code might work for you.

```
byte[] a = { (byte)0xf0, (byte)0x9f, (byte)0x98, (byte)0x88 };
String s = new String(a,"UTF-8");
byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-16BE");
for ( byte c : b ) { System.out.printf("%02x ",c); }
```

Comment: It does indeed work, and it's much simpler than what I ended up with.  Now all I'd have to do is print it in the format I stated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The [`SMILING FACE WITH HORNS`](https://emojipedia.org/smiling-face-with-horns/) character () is assigned to [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) 128,520 decimal (1F608 [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)) in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

You have a choice in how to represent that number with a series of [octets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)).

- [**UTF-8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is one way to represent that number with a variable length, using 1-4 octets.

  - UTF-8 is becoming the dominant encoding in many spheres.
  - Java source code files are usually written in UTF-8, in my experience, and as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2178348/642706).
- [**UTF-16**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) is another way, also variable-length, but using either 2 octets or 4.

  - The Java language [uses UTF-16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1) internally.
  - UTF-8 is generally preferred over UTF-16, as discussed [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful).

In most text-editors, you can simply paste the single character  into your source code. When written to a UTF-8 file, the editor will create the necessary series of octets.

When writing this character to a text file, or otherwise serializing to a stream of octets, you can choose to use either UTF-8 or UTF-16. See:

- [*How to write a UTF-8 file with Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1001540/642706)
- [*How to Open File in UTF-8 and Write in Another File in UTF-16*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27584861/642706)

The following are a couple of trials. You can examine the resulting files with a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) to see the octets.

### UTF-8

This code generates a file in UTF-8 encoding. We find four octets, hex values F0 9F 98 88, decimal values 240 159 152 136.

You can find this code discussed at the [Oracle Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html).

Notice how we specify an encoding for our file, [`StandardCharsets.UTF_8`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8).

```
Path file = Paths.get( "/Users/basilbourque/devil_utf-8.txt" );
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
String s = "";
try ( BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter( file , charset ) )
{
    writer.write( s , 0 , s.length() );
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

### UTF-16

This code generates a file in UTF-16 encoding. We find 6 octets, 4 octets for our single character, plus a prefix of 2 octets for a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) (FE FF). Our four octets in decimal are 216 061 222 008, in hex are D8 3D DE 08.

Same code as above, but we switched the [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) to [`StandardCharsets.UTF_16`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_16).

```
Path file = Paths.get( "/Users/basilbourque/devil_utf-16.txt" );
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_16;
String s = "";
try ( BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter( file , charset ) )
{
    writer.write( s , 0 , s.length() );
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

### About Unicode and encodings

To learn the basics of Unicode and encodings, read the post, [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).